# Syntax error in a simple UPDATE query

Tags: postgresql

I have this query (PostgreSQL 9.1):

```
=> update tbp set super_answer = null where packet_id = 18;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "="
```

I don't get it. I'm really out of words here.

```
                Table "public.tbp"
    Column    |          Type          | Modifiers 
--------------+------------------------+-----------
 id           | bigint                 | not null
 super_answer | bigint                 | 
 packet_id    | bigint                 |
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turned out I've copied some white unicode character and Postgres didn't like it.
In a Python console:

```
>>> u'update "tbp" set "super_answer"=null where "packet_id" = 18'
u'update "tbp" set\xa0"super_answer"=null where "packet_id" = 18'
```

Life can be strange sometimes.

Comment: good. I also copied and pasted a simple update sql, but there was a problem that it could not be executed.

I looked at your advice, removed all spaces and hit the space bar again. It was run.